# How to send a class with a multiprocessing.Pipe member through the ProcessPoolExecutor in Python3.10

Tags: python, pipe, python-multiprocessing, python-3.10, python-standalone

I'm trying to write a progress bar class that supports multiprocessing that will be displayed in a terminal (OS agnostic). I'm aware of packages like tqdm that supports this and have used them before, but this is for a project where I want to only use standard libraries, so no "pip install x" solutions, it would have to work on a fresh install of python3.10 and later.

A stripped down version of the class looks like this:

```
class ProgressBar:
    def __init__(self, total: int, count=0, pipe_rec_connection=None, pipe_send_connection=None):
        self.total = total
        self.count = count
        self.pipe_rec_connection = pipe_rec_connection
        self.pipe_send_connection = pipe_send_connection

        if self.pipe_rec_connection :
            self.progress_listener = multiprocessing.Process(target=self.process_listener)
            self.progress_listener.start()

    def print(self) -> None:
        # Some string manipulation and then calling print()

    def update(self, count=1) -> None:
        self.count += int(count)
        self.print()

    def process_listener(self) -> None:
        while self.count < self.total:
            self.update(self.pipe_rec_connection.recv())

    def multiprocess_update(self, count: int) -> None:
        self.pipe_send_connection.send(count)

    def __getstate__(self):
        return self.__dict__.copy()

    def __setstate__(self, state):
        self.__dict__.update(state)
```

I've tried testing the class like this:

```
def process(progress_bar: ProgressBar):
    time.sleep(random.randint(0, 2))
    progress_bar.multiprocess_update(1)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    conn_1, conn_2 = Pipe()
    p = ProgressBar(100, pipe_rec_connection=conn_1, pipe_send_connection=conn_2)
    p.update(0)
    time.sleep(1)
    with ProcessPoolExecutor(max_workers=4) as executor:
        executor.map(process, [p] * 100)
    print('\nDone')
```

However, with some inspections it seems like process() never runs when ProgressBar is passed as an argument so the progress bar is stuck on 0 with no error messages shown.

A solution that works, but is not optimal since it relies on a variable not tied to a class instance is this one:

```
def process(pipe):
    time.sleep(random.randint(0, 2))
    pipe.send(1)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    conn_1, conn_2 = Pipe()
    p = ProgressBar(100, pipe_rec_connection=conn_1)
    p.update(0)
    time.sleep(1)
    with ProcessPoolExecutor(max_workers=4) as executor:
        executor.map(process, [conn_2] * 100)
    print('\nDone')
```

So what my issue boils down to, is it even possible to pass the class containing the Pipe connection as an argument to ProcessPoolExecutor? And if not, is there a better solution than passing the Pipe connection as an argument? Preferably, the Pipe connection should be tied to a class instance.

Edit: a minimal reproducible example as requested. Comment out `pipe.send(1)` and "uncomment" `progress_bar.multiprocess_update(1)` and `p_list = [p] * 100` to try out the example where ProgressBar is passed as an argument.

```
import time
import random
import multiprocessing
from concurrent.futures import ProcessPoolExecutor


class ProgressBar:
    def __init__(self, total: int, count=0, pipe_rec_connection=None, pipe_send_connection=None):
        self.total = total
        self.count = count
        self.pipe_rec_connection = pipe_rec_connection
        self.pipe_send_connection = pipe_send_connection

        if self.pipe_rec_connection:
            self.progress_listener = multiprocessing.Process(target=self.process_listener)
            self.progress_listener.start()

    def print(self) -> None:
        print(f'\r{self.count}/{self.total}', end='')

    def update(self, count=1) -> None:
        self.count += int(count)
        self.print()

    def process_listener(self) -> None:
        while self.count < self.total:
            self.update(self.pipe_rec_connection.recv())

    def multiprocess_update(self, count: int) -> None:
        self.pipe_send_connection.send(count)

    def __getstate__(self):
        return self.__dict__.copy()

    def __setstate__(self, state):
        self.__dict__.update(state)


def process(pipe, progress_bar=None):
    time.sleep(random.randint(0, 2))
    pipe.send(1)
    #progress_bar.multiprocess_update(1)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    conn_1, conn_2 = multiprocessing.Pipe()
    p = ProgressBar(100, pipe_rec_connection=conn_1, pipe_send_connection=conn_2)
    p.update(0)
    time.sleep(1)
    p_list = [None] * 100
    # p_list = [p] * 100
    with ProcessPoolExecutor(max_workers=4) as executor:
        executor.map(process, [conn_2] * 100, p_list)

    print('\nDone')
```

Comment: First, please provide a [mcve]. Second, from the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#exchanging-objects-between-processes): "Note that data in a pipe may become corrupted if two processes (or threads) try to read from or write to the *same* end of the pipe at the same time. Of course there is no risk of corruption from processes using different ends of the pipe at the same time." It looks like you've got multiple processes trying to use the same end of the pipe at the same time.

Comment: @user2357112 Added an example, thank you pointing it out. As for the part regarding the pipe. I've already read that part and was half expecting it to cause issues/requiring use of a lock for it to play nicely, however I didn't have any issues with the pipe when not passing ProgressBar as an argument, so I'm not sure why that would suddenly become a problem.